# separate thread for continual sleep

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple http server and I would like to define separate thread, where will be running this small code in loop:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    print "I am running ok."
```

original code:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        return

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        self._set_headers()

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=PORT):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

Where/how should I incorporate this While loop in my code with separate thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a function and pass that to `threading.Thread()`.

```
def foo():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print ("I am running ok.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread (target=foo)
    t.start()
    ...
```